# Distribution of an angle between a random and fixed length of 2 vectors

Tags: probability, random

In the diagram below the $r_1$ and $r_2$ lengths are fixed. But the position is random.

How can I get the distribution, PDF and CDF of $D$?

[image: Figure for the question]

Comment: Random and independent?

Comment: I would try to establish $\theta$ as a function of the length $D$ (by the cosine law). Then it is an easy matter to obtain the probability of that $\theta$ given that the total angle is $\pi$.

Comment: @Patricio yes they are random and independent

Comment: @YvesDaoust we did it assuming the theta is uniformly distributed. But we realized it is not. How can I derive when it is not uniformly distributed?

Comment: You have to integrate over all angles that correspond to a given $D$ while applying the probabilities of the angles. For this you need to known their $\text{pdf}$.

Comment: It looks like we can let the coordinates of $A$ and $B$ be $(r_1\cos\Theta_1, r_1\sin\Theta_1)$ and $(r_2\cos\Theta_2, r_2\sin\Theta_2)$, and then calculate the coordinate of $D$ in terms of $\Theta_1, \Theta_2$, and thus we can calculate the pdf of the angle of $D$ in terms of the pdf of $\Theta_1, \Theta_2$. However, if the support is limited to that semi circle as shown on the figure, the intersection point $D$ may not exist, if $\Theta_1, \Theta_2$ is close to each other. So you need to specific the case, or if they are dependent such that $D$ must exist.